# Can you use induction from $n$ to $n^2$ to prove a statement is true for all non-negative real numbers?

Tags: induction, computational-complexity

Suppose we have a statement, and we want to prove is true for all $\mathbb{R}^{+}$. Assume the base case is "the statement can be proven true for any sufficiently small values". So now can we prove the statement by having the induction step be from $n$ to $n^2$?

Thank you!

---

Edit:

The original statement is one of my homework questions, so please do **not** write out the whole proof directly. It looks like they are trying to make the induction step from $n$ to $n^2$, but I am wondering about the validity of the proof.

> The recursion $T(n)$ is: $T(n) = \sqrt{n}T(\sqrt{n}) + n$. Assuming that $T(n)$ is constant for sufficiently small $n$, show by induction that $T(n) = \theta(nlog_{2}log_{2}n)$

Comment: Please, add more context to your question so people can help you better. Which statement are you trying to prove?

Comment: This is extremely vague. Not knowing what "the statement" is, it's pretty impossible to answer.

Comment: Anyway. The usual order relation $<$ on $\mathbb R^+$ is not well-founded (there are non-empty sets that do not have a minimal element). That means that it cannot be used for induction.

Comment: The only comment I would make is: induction is not generally appropriate to prove something is true "for all $x \in \mathbb R^+$".

Comment: A possible approach is to show that the set of all values for which the statement holds is both open and closed in $\mathbb{R}^+$. Since the set is non-empty, it must then be all $\mathbb{R}^+$.

Comment: @LeeMosher Depends on the order that is practicized, doesn't it?

Comment: What you could do is proving that a statement is $(1)$ true for every real number in the interavl $[0,1]$ $(2)$ If it is true for $x$, then also for $x-1$ and $x+1$. Then, the statement is true for every real number.

Comment: I have added the statement in my edit. Please take a look. Thank you.

Comment: If those ‘sufficiently small values’ are smaller than $1$, then squaring them is not going to get you to cover all other reals.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Complexity of $T(n)=\sqrt{n}T(\sqrt{n})+n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50523/complexity-of-tn-sqrtnt-sqrtnn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The homework question you quote uses $n$, and so I wouldn't interpret it as being abut *real* numbers -- especially in computational complexity $n$ is usually taken to *implicitly* range over the natural numbers.

The induction principle you suggest is certainly doesn't work for the reals, or even for the *positive* reals. If it did, you could use it to prove that every positive real is less than $1$ (which is known not to be the case), for example.

You could change the base case to be "the property is true  for $[1-\varepsilon,1+\varepsilon]$ for some $\varepsilon>0$", and then you would conclude the property is true for all *strictly positive* reals.

---

In the actual homework question, I think you need to do something like interpret $T(\sqrt n)$ as $T(\lfloor \sqrt n\rfloor)$. Most probably the problem author imagined that "sufficiently small $n$" includes large enough values that the rounding doesn't upset things anyway.

You can then make do with long induction on the naturals.

Comment: Well, the statement from the homework doesn't even hold for n = 1 though...

Comment: @PrisonMike: Beware of the pitfalls of Landau notation: $T(n)=\Theta(n\log\log n)$ is a statement about the _asymptotic behavior_ of $T$. Despite how it looks, $n$ is _not a free variable_ in that claim, and it doesn't make sense to say that it "doesn't even hold for $n=1$".

Comment: So when the homework says "show by induction that $T(n) = \Theta(n\log\log n)$" what it really means must be "use induction to show some statement that (without too many contortions afterwards) implies $T(n)=\Theta(n\log\log n)$".

Comment: @PrisonMike in the base case, the interval can be changed to $[2-\epsilon,2+\epsilon]$. then you wouldnt have the n=1 problem.

Comment: @cineel: Well, strictly speaking we can't have $T(n) = \sqrt n T(\sqrt n)+n$ for _all_ (real positive?) $n$ and at the same time $T(n)$ is _constant_ for sufficiently small $n$. It seems most reasonable to interpret the problem to mean that the recurrence only holds _above_ the initial interval where $T(n)$ is constant.

Answer (score 0):

Well, induction can be used for the set of natural numbers and more generally any set which is well-founded.
But the set of non-negative rational numbers or reals under the standard ordering is not well-founded (as e.g. the subset of positive rationals or reals has no minimum).
So the answer is no.

Comment: Could you please take a look at the statement I just added to my edits? Thank you!